# ASP.NET 4 Web forms Routing images

Tags: asp.net, routes, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-routing

I'm using ASP.NET 4 Web forms routing, for example like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("page-browse", "{Language}/{Label}", "~/Default.aspx")
```

So the webadress could look like: `http://localhost/mywebsite/eng/home`

In the root of my website I have a folder "Images".

Image display works when I'm in the root of my website, e.g. by using `http://localhost/mywebsite/default.aspx`

But when using routing it doesn't work, because the image relative url will look at `http://localhost/mywebsite/eng/images` instead of `http://localhost/mywebsite/images`

Is there a way to prevent this using ASP.NET 4 Routing mechanism? Or is the only way to use absolute url's to images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things you could try.

1)  Set RouteExistingFiles to false.  This will stop routing on any file that the server matches as already existing.  Only "virtual" urls that match a route will actually be routed:

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
```

2) Use a `StopRoutingHandler` route.  For example, this would stop routing on all jpgs. You could also set it up to ignore the entire images directory.

```
routes.Add(new Route("*\.jpg", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

Comment: the stop routing handler is *i think* the ms recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an `IHttpHandler` implementation that locates the file's absolute path from the virtual path and renders it as a filestream.
2. Create an `IRouteHandler` implementation that returns the http handler I just described if the file has an image extension, or uses the default routing mechanism otherwise.
3. Register the route handler to be used in the route.

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing your images? 
You should just be able to use a virtual path to the site root, using a prefix of '/' (unless I'm completely misunderstanding the question)

e.g.

```
<img src="/mywebsite/images/image.jpg" />
```

Comment: Such a virtual path will translate to:
http://www.website.com/mywebsite/images/image.jpg

And in case the route is mywebsite/language/ it will change to:
http://www.website.com/mywebsite/language/images/image.jpg

You see where the problem is? The image directory path isn't correct anymore in such a case.
A solution would be to use <img src="~/mywebsite/images/image.jpg" runat="server"> but I can't use this because most images I use are manually included in the website by the user using a html editor, so runat="server" cannot be included.